# Why can't I see source in Microsoft's reference source?

Tags: c#

I have a stack trace, and I would like to look at the source code in the methods.

```
at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.ValidateRequestEntityLength()
at System.Web.HttpBufferlessInputStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartRead()
```

If I google `ValidateRequestEntityLength`, I get a [nice result, source and all.](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpBufferlessInputStream.cs)

If I google `StreamToStreamCopy`, it apparently does not exist anywhere.

Why is this? Can I see the source of StreamToStreamCopy *anywhere*?

Very frustrating that referencesource.microsoft.com doesn't actually let you reference all of the source.

Comment: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28600526/ ?

Comment: What assembly is that class supposed to be part of?  I can't find in `System.Net.Http.dll` or `System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll`.

Comment: :'( Do you have a citation on that, by chance @BradleyUffner?

Comment: @DarkBobG how did you find that? Please post an answer! Can't give you enough credit in the comments.

Comment: It is System.Net.Http.dll.  Documented as "ASP.NET Frameworks for VS2013".  [Open-sourced here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamToStreamCopy.cs).

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer, as @HansPassant knows *far* more about this that I do.

Comment: Why is everyone answering in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

The entire source is not available on refrencesource.microsoft.com for all assembilies in the .NET framework. However some parts where re-created for .NET Core, [you can to go to the github page for that class and find it there](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamToStreamCopy.cs)

Answer (score 0):

.Net is now open source! What does this mean? The new stuff's source can actually be looked at. The old stuff? Not so much:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/11/12/net-core-is-open-source/

What's supported?:

> This is a natural progression of our open source efforts, which already covers the managed compilers (C#, VB, and F#) as well as ASP.NET:
>
> C# & Visual Basic (“Roslyn”)
>
> Visual F# Tools
>
> ASP.NET 5
>
> Entity Framework
>
> This takes it to the next level by extending it to the .NET runtime and the core framework.
>
> .NET Core Framework